# How to use bokeh server over https (0.11.0)

Tags: bokeh

I've been trying to use bokeh server to get interactive plots served over an https website. I use an autoload_server generated script to pull plots from the server. However, I've run into problems wherein the autoload.js file obtained from the bokeh server injects http versions of the css/js files into the script.

Is there any way to avoid having bokeh serve http content in order to avoid content mixing errors? Even better, is it possible to configure bokeh to serve content over https?

Thanks!

```js
(function(global) {
 function now() {
   return new Date();
 }

 if (typeof (window._bokeh_onload_callbacks) === "undefined") {
   window._bokeh_onload_callbacks = [];
 }

 function run_callbacks() {
   window._bokeh_onload_callbacks.forEach(function(callback) { callback() });
   delete window._bokeh_onload_callbacks
   console.info("Bokeh: all callbacks have finished");
 }

 function load_libs(js_urls, callback) {
   window._bokeh_onload_callbacks.push(callback);
   if (window._bokeh_is_loading > 0) {
     console.log("Bokeh: BokehJS is being loaded, scheduling callback at", now());
     return null;
   }
   if (js_urls == null || js_urls.length === 0) {
     run_callbacks();
     return null;
   }
   console.log("Bokeh: BokehJS not loaded, scheduling load and callback at", now());
   window._bokeh_is_loading = js_urls.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < js_urls.length; i++) {
     var url = js_urls[i];
     var s = document.createElement('script');
     s.src = url;
     s.async = false;
     s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = function() {
       window._bokeh_is_loading--;
       if (window._bokeh_is_loading === 0) {
         console.log("Bokeh: all BokehJS libraries loaded");
         run_callbacks()
       }
     };
     s.onerror = function() {
       console.warn("failed to load library " + url);
     };
     console.log("Bokeh: injecting script tag for BokehJS library: ", url);
     document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
   }
 };var element = document.getElementById("976c2ae5-68de-4787-815c-852a1de3e3b0");
 if (element == null) {
   console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: autoload.js configured with elementid '976c2ae5-68de-4787-815c-852a1de3e3b0' but no matching script tag was found. ")
   return false;
 }var js_urls = ['http://website.com/static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=b0e2720e424bae5562ceecc6d83c2044', 'http://website.com/static/js/bokeh-widgets.min.js?v=8e88133dddc48883a815d4278dd80f9a', 'http://website.com/static/js/bokeh-compiler.min.js?v=34cb81b761c2c28f1955c7bb98dab3a9'];

 var inline_js = [
   function(Bokeh) {
     Bokeh.set_log_level("info");
   },
   
   function(Bokeh) {
     Bokeh.$(function() {
         var docs_json = null;
         var render_items = [{"sessionid": "nZqXOULM3zcQBaz1GDCOTLVIoa4a0UrlJIMzGCMzCTZk", "elementid": "976c2ae5-68de-4787-815c-852a1de3e3b0", "use_for_title": true}];
         
         Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items, "ws://website.com/ws");
     });
   },
   function(Bokeh) {
     console.log("Bokeh: injecting CSS: http://website.com/static/css/bokeh.min.css?v=486d3195473d3e39ad36f2888fefe389");
     Bokeh.embed.inject_css("http://website.com/static/css/bokeh.min.css?v=486d3195473d3e39ad36f2888fefe389");
     console.log("Bokeh: injecting CSS: http://website.com/static/css/bokeh-widgets.min.css?v=0bbd11cf0fab2f648f3918c073bc9c3d");
     Bokeh.embed.inject_css("http://website.com/static/css/bokeh-widgets.min.css?v=0bbd11cf0fab2f648f3918c073bc9c3d");
   }
 ];

 function run_inline_js() {
   for (var i = 0; i < inline_js.length; i++) {
     inline_js[i](window.Bokeh);
   }
 }

 if (window._bokeh_is_loading === 0) {
   console.log("Bokeh: BokehJS loaded, going straight to plotting");
   run_inline_js();
 } else {
   load_libs(js_urls, function() {
     console.log("Bokeh: BokehJS plotting callback run at", now());
     run_inline_js();
   });
 }
}(this));
```

Comment: It's definitely possible, but I feel like you might need to upgrade to `0.11.1` to accomplish it. I have a vague recollection of some issue being closed after `0.11` but a quick search did not turn it up. You might check out this section of the user guide: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#reverse-proxying-with-nginx-and-ssl  Additionally, you can see the scripts that deploy to HTTPS on the demo site here: https://github.com/bokeh/demo.bokehplots.com (note the site has not yet been re-deployed to HTTPS yet, waiting on a new release)

Comment: Also it would be helpful to see the code you are using to invoke `autoload_server`

Comment: Seems upgrading to `0.11.1` fixed things. It had to do with using `--use-xheaders` with `bokeh serve`. It would probably be nice to have that hint a little more explicity in the documentation. Thanks to the help! :)

Comment: Hi, trying with 0.12.4 over here also has the same problem. Using Apache though and the docs only mention Nginx, so not sure if it just does not work with Apache. Will try the Nginx scenario.

Comment: I'm fairly confident it will work with Apache. But I don't have the expertise with Apache to provide specific configuration guidance, or the time to gain that expertise, unfortunately. If you figure out the correct Apache configuration, we would certainly appreciate a PR to the docs, or a report of the details to the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/bokeh) so that someone else might update them.